# issues with $ symbol while reading from positional parameters in unix shellscript

Tags: shell-script, variable, quoting

I have written the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST=$1
TEST_1=$2

if [[ "$TEST" == e ]];then
echo $TEST_1
else
echo "Input is not e"
fi
```

Now if I will run:

```
sh test.sh e NS3#$xX$56M
```

then output will be

```
NS3#56M
```

That's removing all the `$xX$` charcters. Is there any way I can get the all characters including the special characters?

Answer (score 11):

The reason is that you are not correctly quoting your *input*. The parameter you pass to the script contains `$`, and you pass the parameter unquoted (i.e. simply as `NS3#$xX$56M`), which means it will be subject to [variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). This means that the shell that interprets your

```
sh test.sh e NS3#$xX$56M
```

command to call the `test.sh` script will first try to substitute the `$xX` part with the content of a shell variable (either locally defined or exported as environment variable) `xX`, and - since there likely isn't any - substitutes this part with "nothing", before it passes the result to your script. However, this is the correct functioning of the shell, and hence there is nothing principally wrong with your script (as noted by @roaima).

To prevent this problem, enclose the string in single-quotes which will disable any expansions:

```
sh test.sh e 'NS3#$xX$56M'
```

As a general note on your script:

- Don't use all-uppercase variable names unless you plan to export them to the environment (i.e. use `test` instead of `TEST`) - this prevents unwanted clashes between variables of your script and possibly essential environment variables.
- Use [`shellcheck`](https://shellcheck.net), also available as standalone program on many linux distributions, to "proof-read" your scripts; this will help prevent many errors.
- As you saw from the problem you encountered, [*always be sure to correctly quote shell variables*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary) when using them, unless you positively know that you want variable/glob expansion and word splitting to happen. This also applies to the usage of shell variables in your script.
- You call the script as

  ```
  sh test.sh ....
  ```

  This will override the `#!`-line and use the `sh` shell, which on many systems will be a POSIX-compliant shell that doesn't understand the `[[ ... ]]` operator e.g. Either make it executable and call it as `./test.sh`, or explicitly use `bash test.sh`.

Comment: yes with single quote I can access the value correctly. But that special character string (NS3#$xX$56M) is passed at run time. So manually we cannot put quotes. In stead can we make some changes in side the script by which it wont trim those special characters

Comment: @John That's impossible. You can't recover `NS3#$xX$56M` from `NS3#M`. You need to fix whatever is calling the script with an invalid argument.

Comment: If the thing that calls your script is like `system("sh test.sh " + someVar)` then that system call may well be using /bin/sh to invoke the passed string, so you get `sh -c 'sh test.sh NS3#$xX$56M'`. See if you can do something like `system(['bash', 'test.sh', someVar])` which will avoid the enclosing /bin/sh and leave the values intact.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Do you have any idea under what conditions a shell would keep the `$5` in the sample input verbatim? I would naively think that `NS3#$xX$56M` would become `NS3#6M` (and it does in my bash tests), but the OPs sample output seems to indicate that the "trailing" `$` gets absorbed, too.

Comment: @John, there are serious security bugs implied if your code is just substituting input onto a command line -- think "one of the two ways Western Digital MyBooks are getting hacked this week" type serious bugs. Really, _really_ don't use string concatenation to merge data into shell commands; whatever is doing that shouldn't ever be released to the wild, and you have more than enough grounds to insist that whatever team maintains that component fix it, even if it's not code you personally control yourself.